# Log4j2 : How to configure multiple Appender with same type in Yaml configuration

Tags: yaml, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I'm trying to have 2 RollingRandomAccessFile in the same YAML configuration. I'm able to do it in XML but not in YAML. As a result, I want two files "application.log" and "payload.log".

Here's my working XML configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>

        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="PAYLOAD" fileName="logs/payload.log"
                                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/payload-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="APPLICATION" fileName="logs/application.log"
                                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/application-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" level="trace"/>
            <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION" level="trace"/>
            <appender-ref ref="PAYLOAD" level="trace"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Here's my non-working YAML configuration. The second declaration of RollingRandomAccessFile overrides the first one, resulting with only "application.log" :

```
Configuration:
  status: debug

  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: CONSOLE
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    RollingRandomAccessFile:
      name: PAYLOAD
      fileName: logs/payload.log
      filePattern: "logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/payload-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
      Policies:
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          size: 1 KB
    RollingRandomAccessFile:
      name: APPLICATION
      fileName: logs/application.log
      filePattern: "logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/application-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
      Policies:
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          size: 1 KB

  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: debug
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: CONSOLE
        - ref: PAYLOAD
        - ref: APPLICATION
```

Here's what I tried using List at the Appender level and with that there's no ouput, even the console :

```
Configuration:
  status: debug

  Appenders:
    - Console:
      name: CONSOLE
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    - RollingRandomAccessFile:
      name: PAYLOAD
      fileName: logs/payload.log
      filePattern: "logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/payload-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
      Policies:
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          size: 1 KB
    - RollingRandomAccessFile:
      name: APPLICATION
      fileName: logs/application.log
      filePattern: "logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/application-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
      Policies:
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          size: 1 KB

  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: debug
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: CONSOLE
        - ref: PAYLOAD
        - ref: APPLICATION
```

If I replace the second RollingRandomAccessFile by a RollingFile, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally found the solution, was misusing the list

```
Configuration:
  status: debug

  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: CONSOLE
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    RollingRandomAccessFile:
      - name: PAYLOAD
        fileName: logs/payload.log
        filePattern: "logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/payload-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
        PatternLayout:
          Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
        Policies:
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 1 KB
      - name: APPLICATION
        fileName: logs/application.log
        filePattern: "logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/application-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
        PatternLayout:
          Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
        Policies:
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 1 KB

  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: debug
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: CONSOLE
        - ref: PAYLOAD
        - ref: APPLICATION
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to set different threshold levels for each of the Logger and this is how it looks:

```
---
Configuration:
  status: info
  name: My Application Logger
  thresholdFilter:
    level: debug
  appenders:
    Console:
      name: STDOUT
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"
    RollingRandomAccessFile:
      name: RollingRandomAccessFile
      fileName: logs/app.log
      filePattern: logs/archive/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"
      Policies:
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          size: 20 MB
  Loggers:
    logger:
      - name: org.apache.logging.log4j.test2
        level: debug
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: RollingRandomAccessFile
    Root:
      level: debug
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: RollingRandomAccessFile
          level: warn
        - ref: STDOUT
...
```

The default log level becomes that configured to Root Logger. If you want to override the level, add the level to each `AppenderRef`.

Comment: Lots of lovely options for inspiration here.